# Filtering Elaticsearch query on existence of a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write an Elasticsearch query that will return elements that have a nested field. However, I'm apparently having a good deal of difficulty with it. My mapping for this field looks generally as follows:

`{
    "myType": {
        "properties": {
            "hello": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "foo": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
                    "bar": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

My query is generally as follows:
`{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "hello.foo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

This query returns 0 matching documents even though I know there are matching documents.

I also tried to use the `exists` query inside a `nested` query, but was given an error message about `nested` queries not supporting the `exists` query.

I'm testing this against Elasticsearch 2.3 Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this will help

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "hello",
            "filter": {
              "term": {       // replace term to "match" in case of fulltext 
                "hello.foo": "value to be searched"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

Comment: Haha, I was just about to post that I'd found my answer from an old blog post (http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-nested-mapping-and-filter/). But this is exactly what it said to do (use another filter inside the nested filter to then use the exists filter). I'm going to edit your `term` filter to be an `exists` one and mark your answer correct! Thanks for the help!